# Friggeri-cv: How to produce this particular text position?

Tags: positioning, cv, textpos, friggeri-cv

I'm trying to adapt the [cv-friggeri-x](https://github.com/Nadorrano/cv-friggeri-x) CV template to my needs.

One big problem I'm facing is that I usually make my CV on two pages (yes, I know, that's not the taste of everyone :D ). The problem is that this template was designed to be done only on one page.

To produce a two-column CV, the author wrote an `aside` environment while the right-content is written as the main content.

- The `aside` content positionning is done with the `textpos` package wich places the text block at a particular absolute position.
- Meanwhile, the main content is placed on the right by setting a large left-margin with `geometry`.

The consequence is that **if the main content is too long, a new page is produced with a large left-margin** and I don't want this behavior.

[Default fist page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkMRC.jpg)

[Default second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbzJM.jpg)

What I want is the left margin to be normal for the second page, like [my current CV](https://etienne-monier.github.io/assets/pdf/cv.pdf).

[My cv second page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFQYR.jpg)

Ok, then, I've got two problems:
- I need to find a way to put all the main content directly. Then, if the content is too long, the main content margins should be modified on the second page to have the content in a full-width way.
- Then, I need to adapt the entries second column width on the second page.

#### For the first problem

I previously solved the problem by reducing the `geometry` left margin to be normal, then by defining a new environment `firstpage` wich prints its content inside another `textpos` box on the right of the first page while the main content was beginning on the second page.

The problem is that I need to fine-tune the passage from the first to the second page with the `\end{firstpage}`. Is there a better way to do that ?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{cv-friggeri-x}

\newenvironment{firstpage}{%
    \begin{textblock}{13.4}(6.1, 4.33)
    }{%
    \end{textblock}
}

\geometry{a4paper,margin=1.5cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\header{Etienne}{Monier}{ingénieur en traitement de l'image et du signal}

%% Aside
\begin{aside}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{aside}

%% Firstpage
\begin{firstpage}
    \lipsum[1-10]
\end{firstpage}

%% Second page
\newpage

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```

#### For the second problem

Well, I solved it previously by defining a new length called `colwidth` which value is initiallized to be the small-width length. When switching to the second page, I tune it manually to fit the full width. It looks like

```
\RequirePackage{tabularx}
\newlength\colwidth
\setlength\colwidth{10.9cm}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}[1]{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{\colwidth}}%{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
    }{%
    \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
    \parbox[t]{2cm}{\hfill#1}&
    \parbox[t]{\colwidth}{
        \textbf{#2}%
        \hfill%
        {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} \textit{#3}}\\%
        #4\vspace{\parsep}%
    }\\
}
```

Thanks !

### EDIT

OK, it seems I found how to do that, but I need to execute a macro `\setpagegeometry` at the beginning of each page. I've looked at these two solutions

```
\RequirePackage{atbegshi}
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{\setpagegeometry}}

\RequirePackage{everypage}
\AddEverypageHook{\setpagegeometry}
```

but none worked. I'm sorry to deviate from the initial question, but to give a correct answer, I'm searching for this new issue.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.``

Comment: The differences are listed here: https://github.com/Nadorrano/cv-friggeri-x#whats-new